# Timeout when reading users from page when calling transitive member api on a group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable Function (consumption plan) with two activity functions:

Activity function 1 is to get transitive members from group from first page:

```
public async Task<IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage> GetPageByIdAsync(string groupId)
{
                             await grapClient
                                .Groups[groupId]
                                .TransitiveMembers
                                .Request()
                                .Top(999)
                                .GetAsync();
}
```

Activity function 2 is to get transitive members from group from next page:

```
public async Task<IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage> GetNextPageAsnyc(
            IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage groupMembersRef,
            string nextPageUrl)
 {             groupMembersRef.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, nextPageUrl);
                groupMembersRef
                 .NextPageRequest
                 .GetAsync();
 }
```

I see Activity Function 2 is exceeding 10 minutes. Is there a way to resolve that?

Comment: This might be due to exceeding the query size , could you please try by using top(100) or below .

Comment: I'm using maximum size which is 999 and this is only happening sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can set `functionTimeout` for Azure Durable Functions in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) the maximum timeout for consumption plan is 10 minutes.

You can either reduce the page size by set value for Top method < 999 or check if you can apply some [retry handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp) for Azure Durable Functions.